# How to change the default bootstrap menu icon of sonata adminBundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

Is there a way to change the default bootstrap menu icon of sonata adminBundle in .yml config ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Icons are described here:

```
sonata_admin:
    dashboard:
        groups:
            sonata.admin.group.ecommerce:
                label:           sonata_ecommerce
                label_catalogue: SonataAdminBundle
                icon:            '<i class="fa fa-dollar"></i>'
                items:
                    - sonata.customer.admin.customer
                    - sonata.invoice.admin.invoice
                    - sonata.order.admin.order
                    - sonata.product.admin.product
```

You can find example configuration with icons in [Sonata Sandbox](https://github.com/sonata-project/sandbox/blob/2.3/app/config/sonata/sonata_admin.yml#L51) project.